# Cross browser testing with Selenium Webdriver 3.0.1

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to perform cross browser testing using Selenium Webdriver 3.0.1 but facing issues with IE and Microsoft Edge browser. I am having a 64 bit Windows 10 system on which i have downloaded IEDriverServer.exe 32 bit and 64 bit and MicrosoftWebDriver.exe from Release 14393 and Release 10586 but i am not able to launch the IE or Microsoft Edge using this can anyone please me with this if there are any configurations need to be done

Comment: In order to get any relevant answers please edit your question and add the stack-trace of the error you are getting.

Comment: Is there similar example for IE and Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, version=, platform=WINDOWS}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'DK003800', ip: '10.129.142.76', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: This is the Error i am getting

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) to handle the required binaries automatically. Examples [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples).

Comment: Is there Similar Examples for IE and Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Yes, look [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/InternetExplorerTest.java) and [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/EdgeTest.java).